# View navigation "Popping" on release

Tags: 3d-view

When in free view or official blender input "View Navigation".

Everything is fine untill LMB is pressed to "Confirm", releasing the View Navigation.

The 3d viewport then always moves away slightly from the point I was before releasing/confirming. Changing itself from the view that I took my time to set up.

Has anyone experienced this before and is there any way of getting rid of it?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by "pop", could you edit your question and provide a little more details, perhaps upload an image or animation of this effect happening? It may have to do with preference options like mouse cursor depth and zoom to mouse position.

Comment: Sorry about that, I´ll try to adjust and improve.

Comment: Is it possible you move the mouse when you click?